# run external program in Ruby IO.popen : rescue not working

Tags: ruby, popen, apache-tika

I'm using the [Tika jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) to extract metadata from Microsoft Word doc files but in the case Tika encounters a problem my rescue is not catching the error, instead the scripts exits. I'm on windows 7 with MRI Ruby 1.9.3
I could adapt the doc file but I want to avoid having this problem with future files.
How can I capture this error ?

```
JARPATH = "jar/tika-app-1.6.jar"

def metadata
    return @metadata if defined? @metadata
    switch = '-m -j'
    begin
      command = %Q{java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar #{JARPATH} #{switch} "#{@path}"}
      output = IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |io|
        io.read
      end
      if output.respond_to?(:to_str)
        @metadata = JSON.parse(output)
      else
        @metadata = nil
      end
    rescue => e
      puts e
      puts e.backtrace
    end
  end
```

This is the output I get

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at 'Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOExce
ption from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@1006d75 (JSON::ParserError)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:250)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:244)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:121)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI$OutputType.process(TikaCLI.java:143)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:422)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:113)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x04090000002DA5DB, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:115)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:204)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:163)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:162)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:244)
        ... 5 more
'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
        from C:/Users/.../tika.rb:37:in `metadata'
        from C:/Users/.../index_helpers.rb:55:in `index_doc'
        from index.rb:39:in `block in <main>'
        from index.rb:20:in `each'
        from index.rb:20:in `each_with_index'
        from index.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why not use the [Tika network server](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS) instead of spawning a new JVM each time calling the app? You'd post your content over the network, and get back the metadata or an error, nicely isolated from your ruby

Comment: Also, the specific error in your stacktrace is fixed in the latest version of Apache Tika, is there a reason why you're using an old one?

Comment: @Gagravarr, small business over here, need to minimize the number of serverprocesses that are running, only webserver running is an IIS and a Tomcat that I'd rather not use. The Tika was installed with the Yomi Gem that I desided not to use but brew my own class to interact with Tika. The Tika gives the same error when run from the command line, I'll take a look at that new version.

Comment: @Gagravarr the 1.8 version has the same problem, also in the console, I would also have the answer why I can't rescue that error in Ruby, I often run nexternal programs in Ruby and would like a generic solution

Comment: That code is invalid, you have `IO.popen(...) do |io| ... rescue ...`. `rescue` isn’t allowed there, there should be an `end`.

Comment: Be really careful when passing in arguments that may have spaces in them.  The [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) method can quote them for you.

Comment: you are right matt, i confused it with a method without begin and with rescue, but unfortunatly I added this later as an extra safeguard and it has nothing to do with the error I'm getting, other programs give an error and are rescued but in the case of java it's a different thing apparently. I adapted my question

Comment: @tadman I use the same command in a console terminal and Tika gives an error there also on the few doc's a have problems with, it works with hunderds of other DOC files, regardless of special characters or spaces

Comment: @peter I'm just saying to watch out for that. You write code today that "works fine" and later it blows up in production when someone uploads "Untitled Document.docx".

Comment: ok thanks, but I think I covered that with "#{@path}"

Comment: @Gagravarr, did some benchmarking with my solution and a solution using Tika server (tika-server-1.8.jar), the server solution is more than double so slow, any idea why ?

Comment: @peter No idea... Might be worth asking a new question, and including in it the details needed to reproduce the slowdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your call to `IO.popen` you are passing the output from the child program to `JSON.parse`, regardless of whether it is valid. The exception you see is the json parser trying to parse the Java exception method, which is captured because you redirect stderr with `2>&1`.

You need to check that the child process completed successfully before continuing. The simplest way is probably to use the `$?` special variable, which indicates the status of the last executed child process, after the call to `popen`. This variable is an instance if [`Process::Status`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process/Status.html). You could do something like this:

```
output = IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |io|
  io.read
end

unless $?.success?
  # Handle the error however you feel is best, e.g.
  puts "Tika had an error, the message was:\n#{output}"
  raise "Tika error"
end
```

For more control you could look at the [`Open3` module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) in the standard library. Since Tika is a Java program, another possibility might be to look into using JRuby and call it directly.